# Project with corePlot library cannot run in iPad

Tags: ipad, ios6, core-plot, ios5.1

I have to continue a project that developed by another developer. He has used `CorePlot` library for graphs. I can run this project in my semulator without any issue. But when I try to run it on the iPad, it gives the following error.

`ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Projects/iOS/iPad/HCM_IPAD_Original/21:4:2013mHCM_iPad_1_25/mHCM/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a for architecture armv7s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

My Xcode is 4.5, iOS 6.0
My iPad is iPad 1 and iOS 5.1.1

What is the reason for this and how I can solve this. Please can anybody help me.

Thanks
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for this.

http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/10/05/xcode-4-5-and-file-is-universal-2-slices-but-does-not-contain-an-armv7s-slice/